# Passing pointers to APIs provided by DLL

Tags: dll, operating-system, shared-memory

I came to doubt after doing this.

I had created a DLL in which APIs accepts pointers to some values from application. I am able to access those pointers in DLL.

So i had a doubt how is memory allocated for functions present in DLL and called from application. It should occur in calling proccess memory space. 
Am i right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right: DLL and application shares the same address space, so at system level the is no problem of allocated memory usage.

But you must be careful with deallocation of memory, which was allocated by code from another module. It will work correctly only if:

1. Both modules are built on the same platform (e.g. Visual C++).
2. Both modules use the same heap manager from the third shared DLL (e.g. msvcrt).

Comment: thanks niker but can you tell why memory deallocation is a issue ?

Comment: You must be sure that all your modules use the same instance of heap manager (which implements malloc/free).  
See also https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms235460.aspx